# Laravel redirigir a "public" y bloquear acceso directo

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

Estoy armando una web y en este servidor debo colocar todo el proyecto en la carpeta pubic_htdocs

modifique el htaccess de la siguiente manera para al ingresar a [www.dominio.com](http://www.dominio.com) se muestre la carpeta de public de laravel.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php82 .php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dominio\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://dominio.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Redirigir desde /public/ a la raíz sin /public/
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ https://dominio.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Redirigir todas las solicitudes a la carpeta "public"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

<Files .env>
order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Funciona todo perfecto si ingreso a [www.dominio.com/pagina1/prueba](http://www.dominio.com/pagina1/prueba) por ejemplo o a cualquiera que ingrese...

pero... si ingreso a [www.dominio.com/public/pagina1/prueba](http://www.dominio.com/public/pagina1/prueba) tambien ingresa! y necesito que no se pueda ingresar con el /plubic/ alguna idea?

Comment: versión de laravel? tenes acceso al terminal del hosting?

Answer (score 0):

en el index.php colocas esto

```
<?php
    // Obtiene la URL actual
    $currentURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    
    // Verifica si la URL contiene "/public/"
    if (strpos($currentURL, '/public/') !== false) {
        // Reemplaza "/public/" con una cadena vacía para eliminarlo de la URL
        $newURL = str_replace('/public/', '', $currentURL);
    
        // Redirige al usuario a la URL corregida sin "/public/"
        header("Location: $newURL", true, 301);
        exit();
    }

// El resto de tu código PHP continúa aquí...
?>
```